# generate and validate an SQL query on Angular 6 UI

Tags: sql, angular

I have a requirement to generate and syntactically validate an SQL query on Angular 6 UI. Any recommendations for any libraries/plugins which are available and easy to use would be appreciated.

Comment: "`syntactically validate an SQL query `" is quite a major effort. Good luck

Comment: Not to mention if a library or plugin is involved, you'd be wanting stack overflow, not software recommendations

Comment: No you wouldn't. This is the correct siteto ask for libraries & plug-ins.